# PHP form not submitting to the next page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

The landing page has form but it is not submitting and not redirecting to the next page.After submitting the form, it stays on the same page.

It was alright and was working before but I cant figure out where is the problem.

Code in formPage.php is below:

```
<form action="insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact_form" method="post" name="htmlform" >  
    <input class="frm-input" name="name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Name" required="required" />              
    <input class="frm-input" name="email" type="text" size="30" maxlength="80" placeholder="Enter Email" required="required"/>
    <input class="frm-input" name="jobtype" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder="Job Type" required="required"/>
    <input class="frm-input" name="ent_type" type="text" size="30" maxlength="80" placeholder="Entity Type" required="required"/>
    <input class="frm-input" name="tas_out" type="text" size="30" maxlength="80" placeholder="Task Outline" required="required"/>
    <input class="frm-input" name="l_st" type="text" size="30" maxlength="80" placeholder="Logo style of interest (optional)" />

    <textarea required="required" class="frm-input frm-txtarea" name="message" placeholder="Task Description!!" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" ></textarea>
    <input style="float: left;" type="file" name="image" size="66"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"  name="submitt" value="submit" style="float: right" />
</form>
```

In this file I am trying to get the form information and storing them in database.But this page is not loading after the form submission.

Code in insert.php is below:

```
<?php

    /*
    $name = "";
    $text = "";
    $post = "";
    */

     //echo $name;
     if (isset($_POST['submitt'])) 
     {
      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $mail = $_POST["email"];
      $j_type = $_POST["jobtype"];
      $e_type = $_POST["ent_type"];
      $task = $_POST["tas_out"];
      $l_st = $_POST["l_st"];
      $task_des = $_POST["message"];

      $image_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
            $image_size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
            $image_temp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

      //$date = date(m-d-y);

    echo $name;
    echo $mail;
    echo $j_type;
    echo $e_type;
    echo $task;
    echo $l_st;
    echo $task_des;

    if ($image_type=='image/jpeg' || $image_type=='image/png' || $image_type=='image/gif') {
                move_uploaded_file($image_temp, "img/$image_name");
            }

    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","com");
    $query="insert into details (name, mail, j_type, e_type, task_outline, l_style, task_desc, image) values('".$name."','".$mail."','".$j_type."','".$e_type."','".$task."','".$l_st."','".$task_des."','".$image_name."')";

    if(mysqli_query($connection,$query)){
    //include('test.php');

        echo '<h2>Data submitted successfully!!</h2>';

        header("refresh:1; url=login.php");
    //echo '<a href="test.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="float: right; margin-right: 300px; margin-top: 30px;">Back</a>';
    }else{

        echo "Data not Submitted!";
        # code...
    }


    }

    echo "Data not Submitted!";

?>
```

Comment: Your `formPage.php, insert.php and login.php` are in the same folder?

Comment: Add the full path in action, and for debugging this open action.php in browser tab.

Comment: Your files look ok, did you recently change any css. Just make sure your button is clickable and is not overlapped by some other element. Try an alert on submit of form.

Comment: Do you have any JS on that page that does something with the form/submit button?

Comment: I think this is because you are outputting  echo '<h2>Data submitted successfully!!</h2>';. You need to add ob_start(); on top of your insert.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my fault,there was a typo mistake in the form action.Everything else is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "Data not Submitted!"; // put this line inside the last bracket
```